# Low Search singular/plural matching not working

Tags: ee2, low-search

ExpressionEngine v2.8.1

Low Search  3.1.5

I cannot get the singular/plural matching to work.

I've stripped the results template back to this:

```
{exp:low_search:results
    keywords:lang="en"
    keywords:inflect="yes"
}

  <h2>{title}</h2>
  <br class="clearFix" />


{/exp:low_search:results}
```

The following queries produce different results:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/results?keywords=beers

http://localhost:8080/test/results?keywords=beer
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad; singular/plural matching wasn't added until v4!